An early 20th century philosopher whose approach to teaching was "if you can't explain it to [my granddaughter] then you don't understand it yourself"
I'm not quite sure if it was his granddaughter, it could have been his daughter or niece? If her name was "Rose" then he referred to it as "Rose's rule" or something to his colleagues.  I think he was an analytic philosopher, and possibly American?
The only other detail I remember about this philosopher is that there was a lesser-known philosopher who later married into his family and who died recently in the past 5 years.  This in-law is actually who I am ultimately trying to remember.
Sorry that this is so vague, I simply have no other details I can remember.

I like to say that if you can't explain it to a computer then you don't understand it yourself. As in, you don't fully understand something unless you can write a computer program demonstrating your idea. Computers are less tolerant of vague words than anyone's grandchild :)

@causative Can you give an example of a computer program demonstrating a philosophic argument?

@Sam https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solomonoff%27s_theory_of_inductive_inference is a theoretical solution to the general problem of induction that can be executed as a computer program. But mostly, we don't fully understand most philosophical questions, because we can't (yet) demonstrate them on a computer. To understand how consciousness arises from the brain, for example, we would need to be able to write a computer program taking as input an arbitrary brain, and producing as output the conscious experiences of that brain. We can't do that, so we don't understand it.

@causative A computer only checks the things you program it to check, which generally means it doesn't care about the meaning of any of the terms you give it, or if and how what you said corresponds to the real world. That has some uses (e.g. checking whether an argument has a valid structure), but you can still do a whole lot of handwaving. I wouldn't hold up "explaining it to a computer" as any sort of ideal to strive towards, to demonstrate one's own understanding. (Although now you talk about simulation, which is a somewhat distinct issue, although similar ideas apply.)

@NotThatGuy I'm not saying that just because you can write a computer program that demonstrates your idea, you understand the idea. I'm saying that if you can't write such a computer program, you don't.

Whoever said it, it is true.

Thanks for everyone's answers.  The person I was looking for was Karl Popper, and his teaching method was "Write it for Tirzah" (Tirzah is Joseph Agassi's daughter, and Agassi was a disciple of Popper, and Agassi was an in-law to Martin Buber not Popper).
Joseph Agassi is of course who I was ultimately trying to remember.  I'm sorry that my question didn't quite accurately describe who I was vaguely trying to recall.  Here is the Wikipedia excerpt that I had read a few months ago that lead to my poorly phrased question:

[Joseph Agassi] was married to Judith Buber Agassi – Martin Buber's granddaughter – from 1949 until her death in 2018. Together they had two children, Aaron, and Tirzah, who died of cancer in March 2008. Agassi resided in Herzliya, Israel. Tirzah's name, when she was a child, was often used by Popper in his dictum "Write it for Tirzah!" to explain his view that everyone has the duty to write in a clearly and easily understandable language. Agassi died on 22 January 2023, at the age of 95.


An early 20th century philosopher whose approach to teaching…
This is what I found:
"If you can’t explain it to a six-year-old, you don’t understand it yourself.”  —Albert Einstein
That said, there are many, many variations on this quote, attributed to at least three or four different scientists. Of these, Feynman was the teacher.

Thanks for everyone's answers.  The person I was looking for was Karl Popper, and his teaching method was "Write it for Tirzah" (Tirza is Joseph Agassi's daughter, and Agassi was a disciple of Popper).

@D Beauregard. Do you have the cite for Popper?

You must want to communicate to your reader; you must be
clear, never use big words or anything needlessly complicated.
("Write it for Tirzah," he would say-referring to Agassi's eightyear-old daughter.) Do not use logical symbols or mathematical
formulae, for instance, if you can possibly avoid it. Know logic, but
do not parade it.
Via "IN PURSUIT OF TRUTH - Essays on the Philosophy of Karl Popper on the Occasion of His 80th Birthday" Edited by Paul Levinson

@BeauregardD. Thanks !
